# Reading xls or xlsx file using javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

i am reading one xls file through java script.

```
function upload1()
{
    var ControlCn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\\TEST.xls;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
    ControlCn.Open(Conn);
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    var SQL = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
    rs.Open(SQL, ControlCn);
    if(rs.bof)
    {
        document.write('No Data Avaliable');
    } 
    if(!rs.bof)
    {
        rs.MoveFirst()
        while(!rs.eof)
        {
            for(var i=0; i!= rs.fields.count; ++i)
            {                            
                document.write(rs.fields(i).value + ", ");
            }
            document.write("<br />");
            rs.MoveNext()
        }
    }
    rs.Close();
    ControlCn.Close(); 
}
```

In the third line we are giving path of the xls file that we want to read. Is it possible to dynamically fetch the excel file through one browse button`<input type="flie" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below:

```
<input type="file" id="myexcelfile"/>
```

once the user browses the file, then you can get the path as below:

```
var filepath=document.getElementById("myexcelfile").value;
```

You can use the "filepath" variable in your code for passing the excel sheet name

Comment: i hv tried this and its working alright but what i want is in that third line we are giving the path C://test.xls...what we can use instead of that so that we can fetch excel dynamically.

Comment: I have replied for the same issue.
you can construct the file path dynamically using the filepath variable in my answer.

`var Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = "+filepath+";Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";`

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark my answer as Accepted :-)

Comment: hey ashish if does this then it is not reading ...what to do now...?

Comment: are you getting any js error, if so, can you please share that info. Also please alert the value of variable "Conn" and see what it constructs. This way you can debug further.